# MySQL return 1 or 0 by multiplying the value in other rows

Tags: mysql

I have a table called application. This table has a column named status. A user can have many applications. I want to write a query to retrieve the status of the user's application based on the status as a whole. If every status of the application is 1 then query need to return 1 else return 0. (Logically and each status).

I am using BIT_AND to perform this action. This function displays the right result if there are two or more data to compare. If there is only one record then the value will be 1.

```
For example
0 * 0 => 1 (status) **This is error. Correct should be 0**
0 => 1 (status) **This is error. Correct should be 0**
1 * 0 = 0 (status)
```

My table is as shown below 
[image]

I am using this query.

```
SELECT bit_and(application.status)
from applicant_applications application
where application.applicant_id = 1;
```

This problem can be solved in program easily. But I am looking for something in the query. Thanks in advance

Comment: "retrieve the status of the user's application based on the _status as a whole_": what does that mean? "If every status of the application is 1": every status for the applicant_id? Does that mean that an applicant_id can have  _the same_ applications multiple times? English isn't too precise here.

Comment: @TanoFotang Sorry for my English. Yes a applicant_id can have multiple applications

Comment: `applicant_id` is the user? If yes, can the user have the *same* application more than one time? (Your English is okay. What i meant was, that English is not a very precise way of describing these kind of requirements.)

Comment: A user creates an applicant. And an applicant (applicant_id) can have many applications (Id). Now for an applicant find its applications and calculate the status. That is the requirement

Comment: So you should change "I want to write a query to retrieve the status of the user's application" to read: "I want to write a query to retrieve the status of the user's _applications_" (plural).

Comment: To minimize the confusion I have attached the screenshot of the table structure. If you could help with the query then please feel free to answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182756/discussion-between-tano-fotang-and-bikram).

Comment: Is your query resolved ?

Comment: Not really. Its not solved

Answer (score 0):

You could use a couple aggregation functions to determine the query result.  Something like

```
  SELECT IF(SUM(aa.status) = COUNT(DISTINCT aa.id), 1, 0) as `status`
    FROM applicant_applications aa
   WHERE aa.applicant_id = 1
GROUP BY aa.applicant_id;
```

would be sufficient to check if all the applications have a status of 1.

To test, check out this fiddle:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/26a9bd/1

Comment: Its not getting the right result. By the way why are you comparing sum of status with count(distinct aa.id)

Comment: You mentioned that "If every status of the application is 1 then query need to return 1 else return 0". The suggested fix above counts all the applications (count(distinct aa.id)) and then checks to see if each application has a status of 1.  In other words, if 1 application had a status of 0 then the sum of the status column would be less than the count of the applications and the query result would be 0.